# PageUp not working in GTA V

Tags: keyboard

So i have got an Asus TUF A15 Gaming laptop and it's Pageup and Pagedown buttons are on the Numpad and they require the FN key held to work and i believe it's even worse because it seems like i need Numlock off for it to work. However, regardless of Numlock on or off, neither Pageup or Pagedown ever work in GTA 5. And yes, they do work in Windows and other programs. How can i get around this? Pageup is crucial in GTA Online. I've searched all the forums. Everyone is saying use on-screen keyboard of Windows. But the problem is I'm playing gta v on Pop_os and in my on-screen keyboard PgUp option is not available. Please help.

I've even tried remapping my PgUp key to Rightt-Ctrl(Using Input-remapper). Outside the game, the remapping is working perfectly fine but during the game it does not seems to respond at all.

Please help me. Suggest any ways if you can help me. I recently switched from windows to Pop_os so these things are a bit new for me.